# Writing a base case for a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm implementing a compile-time filter, which basically just takes a compile-time vector (a variadic argument pack) of Enums, iterates over it and tries to find if a certain Enum is included in the vector.

Suppose we have the enums:

```
enum Color
{
  red,
  green,
  purple,
  blue,
  pink,
  yellow
};
```

And a struct `excluded_enums` which is a just a compile-time vector of enums we want to exclude:

```
template <Color... ExcludedValues>
struct exclude_enums
{ };
```

We can then have a meta-function: `is_excluded`, which simply returns `true` or `false` depending on whether an enum is among `ExcludedValues`.

The actual implementation of the compile-time linear search thru the variadic argument pack seems pretty straightforward to implement:

```
template <Color Test, Color Head, Color... Tail>
struct is_excluded_impl
{ 
  static const bool value = (Test == Head ? true : is_excluded_impl<
    Test, Tail...>::value);
};

template <Color Test, Color... Tail>
struct is_excluded_impl<Test, Tail...> 
{ 
   static const bool value = false;
};
```

The problem is that the compiler (GCC 4.7) doesn't like my base case.  It fails with:

> internal compiler error: in process_partial_specialization, at
>   cp/pt.c:4414

At first I assumed this was probably a compiler error, since variadic templates are still sort of new these days.  But, [this bug report thread](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52008) seems to indicate that, while the error message is not very helpful, GCC is correct in rejecting this, because the partial specialization is not more specialized than the primary template because it replaces multiple parameters with a pack expansion.

Okay, so I tried to force it to think the base case is more specialized, by included an extra "count" parameter, which is the number of arguments left in the variadic argument pack:

```
template <std::size_t NumArgs, Color Test, Color Head, Color... Tail>
struct is_excluded_impl
{ 
  static const bool value = (Test == Head ? true : is_excluded_impl<sizeof...(Tail), Test, 
    Tail...>::value);
};

template <Color Test, Color... Tail>
struct is_excluded_impl<0, Test, Tail...> 
{ 
   static const bool value = false;
};
```

But this fails with the same error.  So, is this a compiler error?  If not, how do I write a proper base case that terminates the template recursion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the primary template with a single variadic pack instead:

```
template <Color...>
struct is_excluded_impl : std::false_type {};

template <Color Test, Color Head, Color... Tail>
struct is_excluded_impl<Test, Head, Tail...>
{
    static const bool value =
        Head == Test || is_excluded_impl<Test, Tail...>::value;
};
```